# Как преобразовать пришедшие JSON (\u0430\u043f...) данные в читабельный вид?(Swift)

Tags: xcode, swift

Произвожу выборку даныx с сервера из фала `php` в `JSON` и получаю их используя `Swift 3` для мобильного приложения. Дело в том что получаю в таком формате

```
{"venues":[{"name":"\u0430\u043f\u0430\u043f"}]}
```

Вот код запроса

```
//the json file url
let URL_HEROES = "https://...";

//A string array to save all the names
var nameArray = [String]()

//the label we create
@IBOutlet weak var labelTest: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//calling the function that will fetch the json
getJsonFromUrl();
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//this function is fetching the json from URL
func getJsonFromUrl(){
//creating a NSURL
let url = NSURL(string: URL_HEROES)

//fetching the data from the url
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: (url as? URL)!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

if let jsonObj = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? NSDictionary {

//printing the json in console
print(jsonObj!.value(forKey: "venues")!)

//getting the avengers tag array from json and converting it to NSArray
if let heroeArray = jsonObj!.value(forKey: "venues") as? NSArray {
//looping through all the elements
for heroe in heroeArray{

//converting the element to a dictionary
if let heroeDict = heroe as? NSDictionary {

//getting the name from the dictionary
if let name = heroeDict.value(forKey: "name") {

//adding the name to the array
self.nameArray.append((name as? String)!)
}

}
}
}

OperationQueue.main.addOperation({
//calling another function after fetching the json 
//it will show the names to label
self.showNames()
})
}
}).resume()
}

func showNames(){
//looing through all the elements of the array
for name in nameArray{

//appending the names to label
labelTest.text = labelTest.text! + name + "\n";
}
}
```

Всё работает хорошо, если `name` содержит латинские символы, как быть если `name` содержит русские (`\u0430\u043f..`), как преобразовать в читабельный вид?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В моем случае мне помог следующий вариант

При создании `json` в `php` я указал `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` чтобы не кодировал многобайтные символы юникода

```
json_encode($str, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Нужно не забыть указать где-то на выходе (или потом на входе), что полученная строка UTF-8, а вовсе не ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

формат строки с юникодом для Swift должен содержать фигурные скобки:

```
var upup = "\u{0430}\u{043f}\u{0430}\u{043f}" // русс: "апап"
```

вы могли бы попробовать трансформ:

```
        let wI = NSMutableString( string: "\\u0430\\u043f\\u0430\\u043f" )
    CFStringTransform( wI, nil, "Any-Hex/Java" as NSString, true )
    print("\(wI as String)") // апап
```

но как видите для этого нужен экран обратного слэша.
попробуйте добавлять braces или слэши при создании JSON на сервере или пропускайте при сериализации через ReGex. 
Опять же как вы делаете серилизацию, "\u0430\u043f\u0430\u043f" - это не верный формат строки. Для Swift 4 у вас должна быть структура идентичная вашему JSON. И после парсинга что то должно быть в поле "name" этой структуры. Данная строка не может там находиться, так как она не в формате String.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но тут такая ситуация, при создании `json` я указал `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`  чтобы не кодировал многобайтные символы юникода, на экран выводит `апап`, но в консоль выводит в кодироке, так вообще можно делать ?

Comment: можно делать всё, что не запрещено :). я не силён в серверной части, но если это работает, то конечно. думаю есть какие то best practices для настройки создания JSON с уникодом в php, может быть даже именно для последующего парсинга в Swift.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас все приходит правильно, только разбор уже слегка неверный как для Swift.

Используйте новый подход:

```
// 1. Опишите структуру своих данных
struct Game: Decodable {
    struct Hero: Decodable {
        var name: String
    }

    var venues: [Hero]
}
// 2. Используйте JSONDecoder:
if let swiftStyleJSON = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: data) {
    swiftStyleJSON.venues.forEach {
        print($0.name)
    }
}
// 3. Результат:
апап
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, я честно пока что не силен в Swift, мне выдает ошибку в это строке `if let swiftStyleJSON = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Game.self, from: data) {`  > `Use of unresolved identifier 'data'`, не подскажите в чем ошибка?

Comment: @harbor я просто основные участки описал. Нужно смотреть куда Вы подставили. Нужно было вместо  `try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments)`